# Laravel: changing the location of the Exception handler class

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, api, laravel, domain-driven-design

We are restructuring the folder layout of our application so it aligns more with the `DDD` domain driver design idea.

e.g.

```
/app
   /Users
   /Jobs
   /Authentication
   /Http
   /Console
   /...
/bootstrap
/config
/...
```

Although one problem we are having is relocating the `/Exceptions/Handler.php` class. Our view would rename it to `ExceptionHandler` and place it in the root of the `/app` directory.

We get

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class
>   App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist ...

errors after relocating it.

Im assuming Laravel has a hard dependancy on that file being in that EXACT location, is that correct?

Comment: did you `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to update it's binding in the service container.
Example below is from Laravel 5.2 but I'm guessing it should be the same for all Laravel 5+.

```
// bootstrap/app.php
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class // Change this line with the new namespace
);
```

Comment: Haha, happens to us all! :)